# Undefined reference to functions im not even using?

Tags: c++, header, codeblocks, bgi

So i am still trying to get my broken `graphics.h` lib to work. I'm pretty close to fixing all the weird errors.
I have everything installed correctly.
I'm having quite alot of trouble with the not defined error:

```
    -------------- Build: Debug in LEVEL EDITORRRR (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c "C:\Users\Moustachespy\Documents\LEVEL EDITORRRR\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o "bin\Debug\LEVEL EDITORRRR.exe" obj\Debug\main.o   "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a"
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x28e): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x478): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x48e): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x499): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x4a8): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x4be): undefined reference to `SelectObject@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x4c9): undefined reference to `DeleteObject@4'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x4ec): undefined reference to `SetTextColor@8'
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o):winbgi.cxx:(.text+0x1875): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\libbgi.a(winbgi.o): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
11 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 11 second(s))
```

What can I do about this?
Google won't help me with this.
If you need anything else, just tell me and I'll provide :D

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    initwindow(1000,1000);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Implementation of `initwindow` calls `GetStockObject`. This is probably linked from a windows `dll` file.

Comment: im using windows 10 64 bit. Is that the problem?How can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that you linked to the gdi32 library but you are including the header.

EDIT:
I have no idea how Codeblocks work. Is your instructor forcing you to use that compiler because you can download and use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 for free at https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs it is a much better compiler and give you a lot more details in your debug info. Besides not being able to access your console program settings and very sparse debug info the only thing left I can say is confirm that you are including Windows.h in your entry point source file and if you are not restricted in what compiler to use go with VS 2015 it is the newest Visual Studio using c++ V14 and will be much more user friendly Good luck..

Comment: It s literally exactly the same as all the others just with readimagefile. Trust me i checked

Comment: It looks like many of the core windows API's aren't being linked. These are usually linked in your project settings when you create an empty win32 or MFC project. In order for me to see whats going on...are you using a makefile? What version C++ are you using?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I just started a new codeblocks project and clicked on console application and selected c++. Im rather new to programming ( i started at the beginning of this schoolyear ) so i really dont know if condeblocks is using makefile or not.

Comment: I Edited the answer.. Good luck. Wish I could have been more help.

Comment: Really funny thing because thats what i did about an hour before you answered! But thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Actually your program is for windows gui 32. You should select windows gui 32 template instead of console application.

Comment: John, please specify how to "select windows gui 32 template" more specifically to make this answer more valuable to the asker.